# Java - where to specify what a class does?

Tags: java

I am currently working on a rather large java project, and I am having small problems remembering what everything does right away, and am often continuously looking through the classes contents in order to remember exactly what everything does. Is there any conventional way of declaring what each class / method? I am looking for something similar to python's method declarations:

```
def foo(x):
'''
Takes and integer x and adds 1
'''
return x + 1
```

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, use Alt+Shift+J.  Use this on a method (or constructor) declaration, and it will generate a skeletal javadoc comment into which you can type the description, the meanings of the parameters, and the meanings of the return value.  I use this a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly urge you to learn, practice and write Javadoc!

[How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)

You can write javadoc everywhere, because a javadoc is a comment. The javadoc tool (or your IDE - Netbeans for example) should give you insight when you hover (as appropriate). It's also used to generate the official API documentation. It is an example of "literate programming" and here is an official sample, namely [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Comment: Is this the area between the package name and the class name in netbeans?

Comment: You can comment both the class (before the class name) and methods (before the methods names).  You can also comment on fields

Answer (score 2):

Javadoc comments are used to put description on classes/methods. Javadoc comments can be exported to HTML also for ease of reading.

Follow this:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Here is a class with javadoc comments:

```
/**
 * A Container is an object that contains other objects.
 * @author Trevor Miller
 * @version 1.2
 * @since 0.3
 */
public abstract class Container {

    /**
     * Create an empty container.
     */
    protected Container() { }

    /**
     * Return the number of elements contained in this container.
     * @return The number of objects contained
     */
    public abstract int count();

    /**
     * Clear all elements from this container. 
     * This removes all contained objects.
     */
    public abstract void clear();

    /**
     * Accept the given visitor to visit all objects contained.
     * @param visitor The visitor to accept
     */
    public abstract void accept(final Visitor visitor);

    /**
     * Return an iterator over all objects conatined.
     * @return An iterator over all objects
     */
    public abstract Iterator iterator();

    /**
     * Determine whether this container is empty or not.
     * @return <CODE>true</CODE> if the container is empty: 
     * <CODE>count == 0</CODE>, <CODE>false</CODE> 
     * otherwise
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (this.count() == 0);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether this container is full.
     * @return <CODE>true</CODE> if conatiner is full, 
     * <CODE>false</CODE> otherwise
     */
    public boolean isFull() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the existing interstructure.  Comment you code to support JavaDoc notation.

Most modern IDEs are capable of parsing the JavaDocs and supplying them to you as popups.

It also means that you can generate JavaDoc documentation at a later stage.

Check out [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) for more details